# Attempting to read a file and input it into an array

Tags: c++, arrays

I am currently attempting to read a file into a two dimensional array one digit at a time. The file I am retrieving data is maze.txt (shown below code). The program in its current state compiles, but when the program is ran, nothing is printed and it runs forever. I am assuming that the error is associated with the first for loop.

[This is the output of Chris's solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A3TuW.png)

```
//Input: A txt file containing a 10 x 10 maze of 0s and 1s
//Output: A route from the top left to the bottom right passing through only 0s
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
const int LENGTH = 10;
const int WIDTH = 10;


int main()
{ char mazeArray[LENGTH][WIDTH];
  int counter = 0;
  fstream mazeFile;
  mazeFile.open("maze.txt");
  if(mazeFile.fail())
  {
    cout << "File not found." << endl;
    return 0;
  }
do
  {
    cin >> mazeArray[counter];
    counter++;
  } while(mazeFile.good() && counter < LENGTH * WIDTH );

for(int j = 0; j > 100; j++)
  {
    cout << mazeArray[j] << endl;
  }


  return 0;
}
```

**Maze.txt**

```
0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0
0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1
1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 
0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 
0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 
1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 
1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 
0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 
1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0
```

Comment: `for(int j = 0; j > 100; j++)` this loop will run zero times. Maybe you meant `for(int j = 0; j < 100; j++)`

Comment: If you learn to use a debugger now, you'll learn how to figure this sort of thing out quicker than you can copy/paste/format here, and you'll learn some things in the process.

Comment: Dont edit your question to fix the problems you were originally asking for. This makes it useless for future reades and invalidates already given answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that you are incorrectly evaluating the variable `j` in your for loop.

You have:

```
for(int j = 0; j > 100; j++)
  {
    cout << mazeArray[j] << endl;
  }
```

However, this loop will never execute as `j` starts out at `0`, and then is checked to see if `0>100`. The correct loop to iterate through this would be:

```
for(int j = 0; j < LENGTH; j++)
for(int i = 0; i < WIDTH; i++)
  {
    cout << mazeArray[j][i] << endl;
  }
```

Your secondary issue is that you are trying to read the file stream `mazeFile` by using cin. You should replace the line:

```
cin >> mazeArray[counter];
```

with:

```
mazeFile >> mazeArray[counter];
```

This is not causing it to run 'infinitely' but rather causing it to await an input from standard input. (Most likely text entered via the terminal.)

A fixed code sample is:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
const int LENGTH = 10;
const int WIDTH = 10;


int main()
{ int mazeArray[LENGTH][WIDTH];
  int counter = 0;
  fstream mazeFile;
  mazeFile.open("maze.txt");
  if(mazeFile.fail())
  {
    cout << "File not found." << endl;
    return 0;
  }
do
  {
      // Now accessing the array as a 2d array to conform to best practices.
    mazeFile >> mazeArray[counter/LENGTH][counter%WIDTH];
    counter++;
  } while(mazeFile.good() && counter < LENGTH * WIDTH );

for(int j = 0; j < LENGTH; j++)
for(int i = 0; i < WIDTH; i++)
  {
    cout << mazeArray[j][i] << endl;
  }


  return 0;
}
```

Comment: This does not explain why the program would run forever as reported by the OP

Comment: @tobi303 Well the OP was reading the data from `std::cin`. Initially, I was under the assumption that was intentional, but have updated question to reflect how to use the file stream to read the data.

Comment: Yes actually i overlooked the `cin`. However, I think it would be better if you mention this explicitly and clarify that the program is actually not running forever, but just waiting for input

Comment: I ran the fixed program and i was returned a bunch of random characters, should my array be a char data type?

Comment: @tobi303 I dont quite understand your answer. Should my mazeArray be of int datatype?

Comment: @RoyGunderson do you want to read integers or characters form the file?

Comment: @RoyGunderson I updated the code to read integers, and store them using the 2d syntax. In general, when accessing a 2d array, it is better to access its members using [x][y] rather than [x*10+y]. (The outcome is the same, but it is merely better practice.)

Comment: @ChrisBritt I have pasted this code in to compile and it does not return the 0s or 1s. I attached the output in my main question

Comment: What version of MinGW are you using? I just ran it and it works fine as far as I can tell: http://pastebin.com/iy2cR45b

Comment: @ChrisBritt downloading the latest version, i will get back to you.

Comment: @ChrisBritt  Updated, still same issue

Comment: @RoyGunderson I would honestly suspect that it is some issue you are having with your environment then. I've tested the code on four different systems (Win 8 64bit, CgyWin, Win 10 vm 64bit MinGW, Archlinnux 64bit g++ 5.3, debian 64bit g++ 4.4.7) and have not seen any issues. (Correct and same output every time)

Comment: @ChrisBritt What compiler do you recommend for windows 10 64bit? I dont understand why MinGW would not be working.